# how to add dropdown button with list of items to ckeditor nightly

Tags: php, jquery

Can anyone help me in adding dropdown button with list of items.

So if I click on item that item should add to the cursor position on instance.

[image]

Comment: Its very generic question, post your code to which we can suggest a solution

Comment: Thanks for reply i got solution

Answer (score 1):

I've been doing this with .Net MVC but I took my solution and converted it to PHP.

```
editor.ui.addRichCombo('clientfields', {
    label: 'Client Fields',
    title: 'Client Fields',
    multiSelect: false,
    init: function() {
        <?php foreach($clientField as $field) { ?>
            this.add(<?php print $field->VarName; ?>, '<?php print $field->Name; ?>', '<?php print $field->Name; ?>');
        <?php } ?>
    },
    panel: {
        css : [ editor.config.contentsCss, CKEDITOR.getUrl( '/Content/ckeditor/skins/moono/editor.css' ) ]
    },
    onClick: function (value) {
        editor.focus();
        editor.fire('saveSnapshot');
        editor.insertHtml(value);
        editor.fire('saveSnapshot');
    }
});
```

That will add a dropdown to your menu. I also had issues with it cutting of the label of the dropdown but adding this css to your editor.css file that comes with CKEditor should fix that.

```
.cke_combo__clientfields, .cke_combo__clientfields > a {
    width: 150px;
    margin-right: 8px;
}

.cke_combo__clientfields .cke_combo_inlinelabel {
    width: 120px;
}
```

The widths here can be adjusted to the width you need for your dropdown, but this should let you add $field->VarName to where your cursor is in the editor and replace selected text in the editor. I am not entirely sure about the php syntax here but it should definitely get you pointed in the right direction.